# jQuery function running only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm coding a pretty simple *visual thingy* for a set of list items using jQuery and CSS `-webkit-transform: rotate()`.

This is a sample of what I'm doing:

[image: Sample of the result]

So, pretty straightforward. It even works perfectly! Had been working late into the night last night with this, trying something out and then refreshing to see the result. No problem. However, today, upon resuming my work (i.e. opening up my localhost site from scratch) I realized the rotation was not occurring. So I refreshed and, magically, the rotation appeared.

**ISSUE: As it turns out, the code only runs successfully when refreshing the page. When the page is opened for the first time, nothing happens.**

I've tried changing the code, changing its order, adding this, subtracting that, etc. jQuery always seems to me a very capricious thing.

So here's my basic code.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var min = -3;
        var max = 3;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+random+'deg)')
    });
});
```

Only other two things I can say is that:

1) I'm running it just before the closing `</body>` tag. (Though, in my experience, order issues in Javascript and jQuery result in consistent errors; it's the first time I get a code running only after refreshing.)

2) At the beginning I have a `$(document).ready()` that holds the script which actually builds the list. I'm using the jQuery jPlayer in order to build a play-list.

**UPDATE:** I've created a jsFiddle project to play with. [jsFiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wLWAf/) The thing is, one can't refresh as such, so it's always like first load in the fiddle. Still, it works in order to test out how to make things happen still during first load.

Comment: And what browser would that be ?

Comment: I'm testing on Chrome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, as I am using jPlayer and their ready-made scripts in order to build the list of media whose CSS I want to tweak, I decided that who knows how exactly the list is being built. (Well, anyone who reconstructs the code!) Unless I used `timeout` (as one person commenting suggested) and guess-timated how long it would be *safe* to delay one script to make sure the other is 100% done and the playlist is ready, there'd be, to my mind, no way of ensuring this worked in all computers and all browsers. And, even then, in my experience `timeout` is not the best solution for almost anything! So I decided to fish in the jPlayer original code in order to find the last instance of the creation of the playlist; there, I placed my CSS-tweaking code and now it works perfectly!

This solution will only work for somebody using jPlayer. But, on the other hand, perhaps the issue only arises when using jPlayer (and when wanting to do exactly the same tweaks I want to do!).

So in the *jplayer.playlist.min.js* file one must find this

```
c.playlist.length?b(this).slideDown(c.options.playlistOptions.displayTime) ...
```

Between the `(this)` and the `.slideDown( ... )` one should insert the code one wishes to use. For instance, I did this

```
c.playlist.length?b(this).find('li').each(function() {
    var min = -3;
    var max = 3;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+random+'deg)');
})
.parent().slideDown(c.options.playlistOptions.displayTime) ...
```

And that's that.

P.S. Thanks to all of you who pitched in, answering and commenting!

Answer (score 1):

**With jQuery It Should be:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var min = -3;
        var max = 3;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+random+'deg)')
    });
});
```

Comment: The change you've made is to do the code on DOM `ready` rather than on the window's `load` event, right? That should make zero difference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The thing is that when I execute this code under `$(document).ready()`, nothing happens. Not even when refreshing. I have, under the `$(document).ready()` the script that originates the list: the items called by jPlayer.

Comment: @ lonesomeday, you are correct..but isnt it a good practice in jQuery?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves - depends on wether or not you're doing something that requires just the DOM to be ready, or if you actually need the entire window to be loaded.

Comment: Anywhoo, it doesn't matter in this case, both should fire on first load and on refresh.

Comment: But what if OP is creating elements on the fly?

Comment: Here I need the entire window to be fully loaded, as first I need to build the list using another ready-made script. Once it's all done, I can play around with its settings. And I agree with Adeneo: I don't see how the script is failing on first load.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLWAf/ (here one can't refresh, so, as you can see, the script never works, as it's always first load)

Answer (score 1):

The list builder runs after you do the CSS tweaks. When you refresh the page, it's cached and thus is loaded before the CSS tweaks, so they apply.

You need either to call the CSS tweaks when the list building completes, as a callback, or to make them synchronous in some other way, maybe reordering the code, experimenting with $(document).ready() and $(window).load().

Comment: Hi, Shomz. Thanks for replying. I have a question: if the builder is running after document is ready and the tweaks are running after all has been loaded, shouldn't they be occurring after the list is built? I the idea that `ready` runs much before `onload`.

Comment: I was able to make the jsfiddle work by adding a setTimeout() call around the CSS tweaks.  It looks like even though the list building code is run before that, the list is not being built synchronously.

Comment: Yeah, timeout will work, but it's not the best approach.
@QuestionerNo27 I get around 3ms difference between ready and load using the most basic setup, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/685Xk/ (of course, the load won't work on jsfiddle but you need to make your own html file and run it), or even better test it with the page you're building.

Comment: Thanks for the response, guys. @Shomz according to your test, there'd be no way of setting both scripts to play one after the other consistently in all computers and browsers the way I was doing it. I'm going to have to go fishing inside the jPlayer code in order to find a place where I can return a call to the CSS-tweaks function once all the list items are ready. @Mike Edwards yes, a `timeout`, perhaps also a `delay`, but, like Shomz says, it really doesn't convince me as the best approach. In the past, I've had LOTS of trouble with `timeout`. Perhaps the cure will be worse than the illness.

Comment: Great, glad you got it going! In case jPlayer doesn't allow callback (yet I think it does), you can always create container elements in HTML, then load the jPlayer instances inside them. That way, you don't have to care when what happens, you can just let the CSS tweaks do their thing and jPlayer its own. But either way it seems you'd need to rewrite some of your code.